# how to stretch mplayer to both monitors (fullscreen) in a xinerama setup

Tags: multi-monitor, xmonad, mplayer, xinerama

I am using the window manager Xmonad and have two monitors in a Xinerama setup. I want to display videos with mplayer fullscreen across the two monitors.

But, by default, I want mplayer to be a tiled window.

Until now I have done this manually:

- by pressing the ModMask key and the right mouse button on the lower right corner of the mplayer window to resize it
- and then by pressing the ModMask key and the left mouse button in the middle of the mplayer window, moving it to fit into the two screens.

How can I achive this semiautomatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question was somedays old, and I did not submit it but it was still in my browser window.

In the meantime I have evolved a somewhat hacker brute-force solution. I went to the folder where my `mplayer` binary is and copied it to another name.

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo cp mplayer mplfull
```

Changed all occurrences of *MPlayer* to *MPlfull* in the copied file.

```
sudo sed -i 's%MPlayer%MPlfull%g' mplfull
```

Then I edited my `~/.xmonad/xmonad.hs` file (adding my mplayer copy, that has only *MPlfull* in its file, so that this will also be its class name).

```
myManageHook = composeAll
  [ className =? "Gimp"           --> doFloat
  , className =? "Gimp-2.6"       --> doFloat
  , className =? "Gimp-2.8"       --> doFloat
  , className =? "Xsane"          --> doFloat
  , className =? "MPlfull"        --> doFloat
  , title     =? "Gnuplot (window id : 0)"        --> doFloat
  , resource  =? "desktop_window" --> doIgnore
  , resource  =? "kdesktop"       --> doIgnore ]
```

And then added these four lines in my `~/.bashrc` file.

```
alias mplfull='mplfull -xineramascreen -2 -geometry 2048x1280+0+0 -fs'
alias mpl100='mplfull -xineramascreen -2 -geometry 2248x1480+-100+-100 -fs'
alias mpl200='mplfull -xineramascreen -2 -geometry 2448x1680+-200+-200 -fs'
alias mpl300='mplfull -xineramascreen -2 -geometry 2648x1880+-300+-300 -fs'
```

Now when I type `mplayer someFile` I can watch it in a tiled window. And resize it with the mouse as I ever did.

But I can also view my files with `mplfull someFile` and it’s automatically in fullscreen over both monitors (see the `-geometry` option).

The `mpl100`, `mpl200` and `mpl300` aliases are for videos that would have big black stripes on my monitors because of an aspect ratio that doesn’t fit to my dual-monitor setup. Of course a bit of the video will then be cutted away (outside of the screen), but I like that more than having big black stripes.

I am still curious if there are better and easier solutions. Maybe a Xmonad solution?

### Update

The `mpl100` and so on **is not needed**. One can just use the mplayer standard keys `e` and `w` to zoom in and zoom out (called **change pan-and-scan range** in mplayer manual).